# Count startswith with linq

Tags: c#, linq

So I have a question regarding how to count the starts with of a string in linq. Let me explain with some test cases

**Test case #1**

```
var target="test";
var source="test2";
```

The output should be 4

**Test case #2**

```
var target="te";
var source="test2";
```

The output should be 2

**Test case #3:**

```
var target="tet";
var source="test2";
```

The output should be 0. Because the source do not starts with target

So I came up with this function:

```
private int CountStartsWith(string source, string target)
{
  if (!source.StartsWith(target))
      return 0;

  return source.ToCharArray()
      .Zip(target.ToCharArray(), (s1, s2) => (s1 == s2))
      .TakeWhile(match => match)
      .Count();
}
```

It works for the test cases that I have. But my question is can this be done in an easier way?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
if (!source.StartsWith(target)) return 0;
return target.Length;
```

Comment: Now I feel really stupid ;) . Thank you. I will accept the answer

Comment: Sometimes the obvious answer is the hardest to find. I had similar cases.

Comment: I would recommend not using a negative condition when it can be easily avoided.

Answer (score 4):

You may try

```
return source.StartsWith(target, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) ? target.Length : 0;
```